# How much dungeon should I plan for a three-hour one-shot of Torchbearer?

Tags: time, one-shot, torchbearer

I want to showcase Torchbearer to some people, in a block with a length of three hours. How many turns and rooms should I put in there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did run a 3-hour game of torchbearer a few days ago, in which the players took 8 turns (including 2 full conflicts) exploring 5 rooms to some extent.

In my game today, a bit over three hours included 7 tests exploring 9 rooms very carefully with many good ideas, significantly helped by the fact they were only 2 (so less coordination and repetition necessary) and I was quite lenient, so I don't think this is representative.

On RPGGeek, [Pete reports](https://rpggeek.com/thread/1042727/my-first-con-game) of a 3 hours convention slot and says

> • No Conflicts. Nobody had played the game before, so given our time
>   constraint I opted to dispense with the Conflict sub-system and just use
>   regular Tests to resolve situations. Based on my Mouse Guard experience, I
>   reckon explaining the Conflict system and actually playing it out would
>   have soaked another half hour of our time.
>
> • Checks. We had ~12 Tests in the entire game.

If I could follow his discussion correctly, his party managed to explore 4 of the 8 rooms in his dungeon.

Judging from this, you should expect *one room per half an hour of play* at most, with maybe two to three turns in each room.